# Distributed Compiling on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, compile, distributed-computing

I read about distcc for distributed compiling on Linux systems. Since I have to compile a big project quite often, I was wondering if there are methods on Windows on how to distribute that onto several machines. I found this website but it seems [rather outdated](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Distcc_With_MSVC).

Are there systems besides distcc or is anyone successfully using this? I use Visual Studio 2008/2010 on Windows 32 bit and 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most widespread is a commercial addon called [Xoreax Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/). It works really nice, absolutely seamlessly, no need to install any developer tools or SDK on any participating machines.

It supports 2008 and all versions before, both 32b and 64b, but 2010 is not ready yet (it is expected this year).

*Note: You might perhaps get better answers on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sccache is not only a shared caching system but also supports distributed compilation:
https://github.com/mozilla/sccache/blob/master/docs/DistributedQuickstart.md